# Cannot Uninstall Application for Desktop Wallpapers

Tags: macos, applications

I installed an app for desktop wallpapers on a site called Kuvva.com.  It shows up as Purchased in the Application Store but has an option to install it, even though it shows up in System Preferences as already installed.  When I try to click on it, either in App Store to install or in System Preferences to send it to trash, it continues to say cannot delete because it's still open, but I do not see any options to allow me to close it.
I've tried to go over to Desktop/Screensavers where the picture keeps showing up every morning, but there's no way to get rid of it or close it there either.

Answer (score 1):

You can close the Kuvva App via the menu icon.

After that you can drag the application to the trash - enter you user password. Your done!

[image]